# apache .htaccess url rewrite doesn't work without slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache, trying to map different domain into different directory using  .htaccess. Users access different directory when they type different domains. I use the rules below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www.)?mydomain.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/domaindir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /domaindir/$1/ [L]
```

Everything works fine, except when I type domain.com/dir(without /), the browser will redirect to domain.com/domaindir/dir, I just want it stay in  domain.com/dir. If I add  / in the end, it will work fine.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

---

Thank you  anubhava,after using your code,I got another problem. when I typed mydomain.com,I will got 404,I don't know why it just access index.php instead of index.html,but if I typed  mydomain.com/dir, it can fetch the index.html and works fine.the error log is below

```
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/xampp/htdocs/ -> 
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^((?!domaindir/).*?)/?$' to uri ''
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/xampp/htdocs/ -> 
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^((?!domaindir/).+?)/?$' to uri ''
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] pass through D:/xampp/htdocs/
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/xampp/htdocs/index.php -> index.php
[perdir D:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^((?!domaindir/).*?)/?$' to uri 'index.php'
```

I still found  stay in mydomain.com/dir will cause many files 404,how can I redirect to mydomain.com/dir/,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash for directories.

Try this code instead:

```
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!domaindir/).*)$ domaindir/$1 [L,NC]

# add a trailing slash now
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Very difficult to read this from comment. Can you edit your question and post it there.

Comment: sorry anubhava,I have added it above.

Comment: check updated code and make sure you use a new browser to test it.

Comment: yes,it works fine now, thanks ,you are so nice,moreover, can I redirect mydomain.com/dir to mydomain.com/dir/ ?

Comment: yes, the only problem  is it rewrite all my domaindir/ path  to domaindir/index.php, and got 404,I saw it in the log, not the browser, I only have index.html inside the directory.